# Python dictionary TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

When I access the dictionary in my Python blackjack game:

```
import random
deck= {'K ♥':'10' ,'Q ♥':'10','J ♥':'10','10 ♥':'10','9 ♥':'9','8 
♥':'8','7 ♥':'7','6 ♥':'6','5 ♥':'5','4 ♥':'4','3 ♥':'3','2 ♥':'2','A ♥':'11','K◆':'10','Q◆':'10','J◆':'10','10◆':'10','9◆':'9','8◆':'8','7◆':'7','6◆':'6','5◆':'5','4◆':'4','3◆':'3','2◆':'2','A◆':'11','K ♣':'10','Q ♣':'10','J ♣':'10','10 ♣':'10','9 ♣':'9','8 ♣':'8','7 ♣':'7','6 ♣':'6','5 ♣':'5','4 ♣':'4','3 ♣':'3','2 ♣':'2','A ♣':'11','K ♠':'10','Q ♠':'10','J ♠':'10','10 ♠':'10','9 ♠':'9','8 ♠':'8','7 ♠':'7','6 ♠':'6', '5 ♠':'5','4 ♠':'4','3 ♠':'3','2 ♠':'2','A ♠':'11'}
number= random.choice(list(deck.keys()))
del deck[number]
number2= random.choice(list(deck.keys()))
print(number)
print(number2)
value1 = int(deck.get(number))
value2 =int(deck.get(number2))
print(value1+value2)
```

It keeps saying there is a typeerror, I cannot add a none 
type or a string:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a
>   number, not 'NoneType'

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why is there a `del` statement? Any significance?

Comment: @SruthiV, I assume the `del` statement is to remove the card from the deck before the second card is drawn as you shouldn't be able to draw two identical cards from a single deck.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is basically correct but you have some of your operations in the wrong order.  You need to get the first card's value before you delete it from the deck, not after.  My rework of your code:

```
import random

deck = {
'K ♥':10, 'Q ♥':10, 'J ♥':10, '10 ♥':10, '9 ♥':9, '8 ♥':8,
'7 ♥':7, '6 ♥':6, '5 ♥':5, '4 ♥':4, '3 ♥':3, '2 ♥':2, 'A ♥':11,
'K ◆':10, 'Q ◆':10, 'J ◆':10, '10 ◆':10, '9 ◆':9, '8 ◆':8,
'7 ◆':7, '6 ◆':6, '5 ◆':5, '4 ◆':4, '3 ◆':3, '2 ◆':2, 'A ◆':11,
'K ♣':10, 'Q ♣':10, 'J ♣':10, '10 ♣':10, '9 ♣':9, '8 ♣':8,
'7 ♣':7, '6 ♣':6, '5 ♣':5, '4 ♣':4, '3 ♣':3, '2 ♣':2, 'A ♣':11,
'K ♠':10, 'Q ♠':10, 'J ♠':10, '10 ♠':10, '9 ♠':9, '8 ♠':8,
'7 ♠':7, '6 ♠':6, '5 ♠':5, '4 ♠':4, '3 ♠':3, '2 ♠':2, 'A ♠':11
}

card1 = random.choice(list(deck))
value1 = deck.get(card1)
del deck[card1]

card2 = random.choice(list(deck))
value2 = deck.get(card2)

print(card1)
print(card2)
print(value1 + value2)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
A ◆
9 ♥
20
>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code provided is somewhat complex and it is rather simple to use `random.sample` function.

Instead of deleting as both do the same operation:

```py
import random

deck = {
    'K ♥':10, 'Q ♥':10, 'J ♥':10, '10 ♥':10, '9 ♥':9, '8 ♥':8,
    '7 ♥':7, '6 ♥':6, '5 ♥':5, '4 ♥':4, '3 ♥':3, '2 ♥':2, 'A ♥':11,
    'K ◆':10, 'Q ◆':10, 'J ◆':10, '10 ◆':10, '9 ◆':9, '8 ◆':8,
    '7 ◆':7, '6 ◆':6, '5 ◆':5, '4 ◆':4, '3 ◆':3, '2 ◆':2, 'A ◆':11,
    'K ♣':10, 'Q ♣':10, 'J ♣':10, '10 ♣':10, '9 ♣':9, '8 ♣':8,
    '7 ♣':7, '6 ♣':6, '5 ♣':5, '4 ♣':4, '3 ♣':3, '2 ♣':2, 'A ♣':11,
    'K ♠':10, 'Q ♠':10, 'J ♠':10, '10 ♠':10, '9 ♠':9, '8 ♠':8,
    '7 ♠':7, '6 ♠':6, '5 ♠':5, '4 ♠':4, '3 ♠':3, '2 ♠':2, 'A ♠':11
}

card1, card2 = random.sample(list(deck.keys()), 2)
value1 = deck.get(card1, 0)
value2 = deck.get(card2, 0)

print(card1)
print(card2)
print(value1 + value2)
```

The sample output looks like this:

```
A ♥
9 ◆
2
```